# Not getting anything from GET request

Tags: php

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

        $movie_id=$_GET['id'];

        $sql="SELECT * FROM movies WHERE movie_id='$movie_id'";

        $run_sql=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_sql)) {

            $id=$row['movie_id'];
            $name=$row['Name'];
            $desc=$row['Description'];

            echo "<div id='breadcrumb'><a href='index.php'>Home</a> > <a href='movies.php'>Movies</a> $name</div>
    <div id='description'>
        <h1>$name</h1>
        <p>$desc</p>";
    }
}
```

this is the code and its shows nothing except the url ID which is passing through GET no other details are showing no errors either ,

Comment: What is the URL of getting this `id` via GET method??

Comment: How are you getting the ID into the URL?

Comment: try to print var_dump($_REQUEST) and check which is method or you can get id or not.

Comment: For the verification of passing `id` you can use `if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] != "") {`

Comment: Try this 

`"SELECT name FROM movies WHERE movie_id='". mysql_real_escape_string( $movie_id ) ."';" `

Your selection is the probblem

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Url is showing the ID like single.php?movie=3 . its just not displaying the data against this ID

Comment: So you get NO OUTPUT at all?

Comment: And you are sure that there is a row with the ID=3 in your database

Comment: Yes i know prepared statements is good but the main issue here is not getting the data against that id , and i will use prepared statements soon :)

Comment: Nope no output at all

Comment: Is this the COMPLETE script? If not show all the script

Comment: yes i checked the row and query too in phpmyadmin , i think there is a problem in echoing this thing

Comment: function single_page(){

 global $connect;

 if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  
  $movie_id=$_GET['id'];

  $sql="SELECT * FROM movies WHERE movie_id='$movie_id'";
  
  $run_sql=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_sql)) {
   
   $id=$row['movie_id'];
   $name=$row['Name'];
   $desc=$row['Description'];
   

    
   echo "
 <div id='breadcrumb'><a href='index.php'>Home</a> > <a href='movies.php'>Movies</a> $name</div>
    <div id='description'>
        <h1>$name</h1>
        <p>$desc</p>";}
}
}

Comment: Ha ha ha.. Your URL shows the GET parameter as `single.php?movie=3`, That is `movie` and you catch this as `id`.

Comment: Your URL is `single.php?movie=3` and you're checking for `$_GET['id']`…?!

Comment: how did i miss that :p , thanks Frayne ,

Comment: It is solved now , thanks everyone , Happy coding

Comment: [*facepalm*](http://img.memecdn.com/Facepalm_o_92428.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The main issue is with the URL.**

Your URL is `single.php?movie=3` and you're checking for `$_GET['id']`. So change your `id` by `movie`.

For the future, you have to code that is SQL Injection free and follow the Instruction given by **@RiggsFolly**.

Comment: How did I miss that, wooops

Comment: May be this is the Minor things, But at the very first time i guess that he made a mistake with the URL, That's why i ask the URL in the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

In these situations you should add some error checking to your code. In fact you should always be error checking

```
<?php

// some people develop on LIVE servers so make sure
// all error reporting is on while developing a script
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

function single_page(){ 
    global $connect;

    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

        $movie_id=$_GET['id'];

        $sql="SELECT * FROM movies WHERE movie_id='$movie_id'";

        $run_sql=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

        if ( ! $run_sql ) {
            // output the error returned by the database
            echo 'SQL ERROR: ' . mysqli_error($connect);
            exit;
        }

        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_sql)) {

            $id=$row['movie_id'];
            $name=$row['Name'];
            $desc=$row['Description'];

            echo "<div id='breadcrumb'><a href='index.php'>Home</a> > <a href='movies.php'>Movies</a> $name</div>
                    <div id='description'>
                         <h1>$name</h1>
                         <p>$desc</p>
                    </div>";
        }
    }
}
```

This should at least tell you what the error is, if in fact it is generating an error in the compilation or execution of the query.

Comment: Minor mod, as I had not seen your comment with all code

Comment: Ahh I see it was a face-palm moment, maybe this will be useful in the future